# How can I get some data from jQuery and call Html.ActionLink with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, html.actionlink

I have hidden Html.ActionLink, where "Delete" - Action name, "Students" - controller name:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete student", "Delete", "Students", new { id = "" }, new { @id = "DeleteButton", @style = "visibility:hidden;" })
```

And jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#students_table').DataTable();

        $('#btnDelete').click(function () {
            var studentId = table.row('.selected')[0]; //this give me correct id
            //alert(studentId); 
            if (studentId) {
                var href = "?id=" + studentId;
                //$("#DeleteButton").attr(href).click();
                //$('#DeleteButton').attr("?id=" + encodeURIComponent(studentId)).click();
            }
            table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
        });

    });
</script>
```

My problem in calling ActionLink with Id which I got (`$("#DeleteButton").attr(href).click();`)

P.S. #btnDelete - this is id for simple button in html

Comment: Why aren't you using `@Html.ActionLink("Delete student", "Delete", "Students", new { id = "" }, new { @id = "DeleteButton" })` in your table?

Comment: Next to each record? i think it's more comfortable if I can choose record and then delete it with only one button

Comment: I think then I would do the delete with ajax. see answer:

Answer (score 1):

Do the delete with ajax:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#students_table').DataTable();

        $('#DeleteButton').click(function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();

            var studentId = table.row('.selected')[0]; //this give me correct id
            //alert(studentId); 
            if (studentId) {
                $.get( "URL_TO_BACKEND?id=" + studentId, function() {
                    table.row('.selected').remove().draw(false);
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

> http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: good idea, although, purely by convention, a HTTP API request which performs a data change (rather than just fetching existing data) would normally by done via a POST, PUT, or even, in this case a DELETE, rather than a GET. But that's just a convention, to make the functionality better match the method name. The basic idea to use ajax is sensible.

Comment: I can change Html.ActionLink on Ajax.ActionLink, and it will be Ajax, but this don't solve my problem, sorry

Comment: @Alexandr Ajax.ActionLink is not the same, read the code in the answer.

Comment: @ADyson, I completely agree with you. However, I do not see backend code in his question, changing the request method will likely require a change in the backend. I did not want to answer with all kinds of best practices but just wanted to hand a working solution.

Comment: @MikeBovenlander that's true, just wanted to mention it for future readers, and/or the OP if they want to consider changing their backend code. Please be assured my comment is not a criticism of your answer.

Comment: @MikeBovenlander I've tried it, but it redirected me on localhost/students/delete, without "?id=". I have this code on GitHub, if you have time and interest you can check, thanx! https://github.com/aki295/SchoolManagementSystem/blob/Test/SchoolManagementSystem/Views/Students/Index.cshtml

Comment: @Alexandr i've added: `event.preventDefault();` this is to prevent the rest of the button click event to continue. https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: @MikeBovenlander with this corrections this code just deleted rows from datatable, without deleting data from database, didn't redirect on page with delete functional